# How can I change the color of a polygon on mouse hover in Cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I need to make a polygon highlight on mouse hover and restore its color and appearance once the mouse is moved out of the polygon.

I tried this with `ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE` event handler but I am not able to restore the appearance when mouse is moved out of polygon in this case.

I tried https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Polygons.html (http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/polygons.html)

This file in Sancastle. It has inline comments like `// For highlighting on mouseover in Sandcastle.`

But it is not working as expected.

Is there any way in cesium to achieve this? or am I missing something?

Comment: "// For highlighting on mouseover in Sandcastle."  is for highlighting the polygon code in left section in sandcastle http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=polygons.html&label=undefined :(

Comment: "I tried this..." Can you show us your code?

Comment: @dgiugg, the steps I follow to do this : 1. Get the properties and coordinates ofpicked polygon. 2. Remove the picked polygon. 3. Redraw the polygon with different color with properties and coordinates i get in step 1.

Comment: TY, but giving your code (by editing the question) would be clearer! Two objections: 1. You don't need to remove the polygon and display a new one, you could just use `polygon.material.uniforms.color`. 2. You said the problem was when you leave the polygon with the mouse. Maybe it is an event handler problem. But you need to show us the corresponding code to help us identify the problem! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ["Picking" example](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Picking.html&label=Showcases) in Sandcastle, and click on the button that says "Drill-down picking."

There are different ways to accomplish what you describe, but the above demo makes use of a Cesium [CallbackProperty](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CallbackProperty.html) and provides a callback that will return either the polygon's normal color or the highlight color, depending on the "picked" status.  Note that multiple overlapping polygons can be picked at the same time with this method.

The mouse move handler then just controls membership of the `pickedEntities` list, and the polygons choose appropriate colors for themselves based on their membership in that list.

Comment: Thanks!! As you said "There are different ways to accomplish what you describe". Can you summarize some of them?